# Evaluating ranking quality given ordinal values

Tags: model-evaluation, ranking

I have a regression model which attempts to predict an F1-score given shared input features of a pair of models. I understand how to evaluate the quality of my regression model through using metrics which compares the actual v. predicted scores and the disparity between them. However, I am more interested in the position of these best models rather than the difference in their scores.

Suppose I didn't care about how well it predicts the score but rather the ranking of the set of input features, and suppose I didn't care about whether these rankings were exact but how close these rankings were to being accurate, how would I go about evaluating the quality of this ranking rather than the accuracy of regression or are they effectively one and the same? I am a little new to ranking problems as a whole.

For example, below I have the Predicts vs. Actual F1 for each model, and the rank of each prediction vs. the actual rank (w.r.t to F1).

```
    Preds       F1      F1_Rank Preds_Rank
0   0.579676    0.683082    2   1
1   0.561891    0.657691    24  2
2   0.557903    0.638249    58  3
3   0.556324    0.644040    51  4
4   0.555647    0.637684    59  5
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
93  0.113800    0.632650    69  94
94  0.102133    0.628237    74  95
95  0.098296    0.619802    85  96
96  0.058307    0.673273    5   97
97  -0.039698   0.617008    89  98
```

To clarify, I'm not particularly interested in how close `0.5796...` is to `0.6830...` but rather how accurately my model predicts the best `Model` (removed for better formatting), i.e. so that a `Preds_Rank` of 1 and `F1_Rank` of 2 would be a desired outcome (with position considered and important) and `Preds_Rank` of 24 and `F1_Rank` of 2 undesirable given the distance between ranks.

Ideally I'd like the score to strongly consider the position of these ranks and penalise on those pairs of ranks with greater disparity.

Comment: So you basically want to compare a predicted ranking to a given true one? You could compute a Spearman's rank correlation, or just add absolute values of differences. You may also care more about the higher ranks, so you can weight them up in the computations. Ultimately you are free to define your "loss function" as you see fit; Spearman would probably be seen as simple "default" choice.

Comment: It seems as if weighted Spearmans works by assigning individual weights to each rank. So if I had 100 samples and cared the most about the top-10, how would I assign weights to the rest? Since I'm only particularly interested in how well it gets the top-N correct.

Comment: Anything goes really. A radical version would assign weight 1 to the top 10 and weight zero to the others, but that may be a somewhat artificial cut. You could also start with weight 1 for no. 1, assign weight 1/2 for no. 10 and interpolate linearly (also below 10). You'd also have to think of whether you'd want to weight up the true top ones or the predicted top ones - weighting the true top ones up is probably better because of comparability.